# WEB API 2 Routes with id

Tags: rest, routes, asp.net-web-api2

I have an Owin Web API 2 project I am trying to use the following route

**domain/controller/2000**

Where the Id is the 2000

Within the controller I have an action defined as follows

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{id}")]
public IHttpActionResult Get(string id)
{
    return Ok(_someService.GetSomeObject(id));
}
```

I am also using the **RoutePrefix** as follows

```
[RoutePrefix("caption")]
```

Within the Owin Configuration method I have declared the following Routes

```
webApiConfiguration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "api",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { Controller = "values" }
);
```

I am getting the following error

**No action was found on the controller 'Controller' that matches the name '2000'**

Comment: Do you need to call `MapHttpAttributeRoutes()`?

Comment: @Lloyd no that was the answer thanks. put it as an answer and i'll mark it up ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removing the we webApiConfiguration.Routes.MapHttpRoute section completely and adding id:int as I really wanted an int instead of a string has fixed the issue. I think there may have been a misamtch between standard routing and attribute routing and for probably good reason as sthe standard model is MVC based.

Answer (score 0):

You are using attribute routing:

`[Route("{id}")]`

However have you made sure to tell the Web API to use it? Try adding this to the  configuration code:

```
webApiConfiguration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

For further information [see here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2).